# SQL: Pull rows based on sequence of values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to pull rows of data based on the existence of certain values that exist in a specific sequence.

Here's an example of the data:

| Header | EventId | EventDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 67891882 | 382 | 2022-01-21 09:29:50.000 |
| 67891882 | 81 | 2022-01-21 09:03:23.000 |
| 67891882 | 273 | 2022-01-21 09:03:51.000 |
| 67891882 | 77 | 2022-01-21 09:05:58.000 |
| 67891882 | 2 | 2022-01-21 09:29:48.000 |

The results I need are to capture the Header and the EventDate for EventId=81. Further criteria include:

- EventID 81 is the "start" and EventID 77 is the "end"
- Any number of other events can exist between these two with the exception of (60, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 83, 85, 86, 87, 103, 154, 166, 197, 199)

So in the example above, Eventid 81 with EventDate `2022-01-21 09:03:23.000` would qualify as a row I want to pull as 273 is not in the exception list.

**ATTEMPT:** I have tried the following query

```
SELECT *
FROM #Table
WHERE EventDate BETWEEN (SELECT EventDate
                         FROM #Table
                         WHERE EventId = 81)
                    AND (SELECT eventdate
                         FROM #Table
                         WHERE EventId = 77)
    AND EventId NOT IN (60, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 83, 85, 86, 87, 103, 154, 166, 197, 199)
ORDER BY 3
```

But I was immediately confronted with the fact that my sub-queries return more than one result, so this won't work (I was using this to test a singular Header # example, which worked fine). So now I'm not quite sure how to proceed. I'd hate to think that I'd be forced to use a `CURSOR`, mostly because my source data is comprised of 266 million rows.

I had also previously tried using the `LAG()` function to find my "starting point", but that possibility seemed to dissipate once the request started becoming more and more complex (with the addition of the exclusion list as well as the fact that there could be 1 or 40 rows in between the 81 and 77).

---

How should I proceed with this? Here's some example data to play with. The Header can be thought of as a parent key, associated with any number of EventID (representing a specific action) and the EventDate with when this occurred:

```
create table #data (header int, eventid int, eventdate datetime)

insert into #data 
values
('62252595',    '22',   '5/23/2021  12:34:02 PM'),
('62252595',    '81',   '5/23/2021  12:34:03 PM'),
('62252595',    '29',   '5/23/2021  12:34:12 PM'),
('62252595',    '40',   '5/23/2021  12:34:27 PM'),
('62252595',    '22',   '5/23/2021  12:35:02 PM'),
('62252595',    '22',   '5/23/2021  12:36:12 PM'),
('62252595',    '37',   '5/23/2021  12:36:36 PM'),
('62252595',    '77',   '5/23/2021  12:37:04 PM'),
('62252595',    '6',    '5/23/2021  12:37:52 PM'),
('63252595',    '39',   '5/23/2021  12:38:01 PM'),
('63252595',    '81',   '5/23/2021  12:38:04 PM'),
('63252595',    '37',   '5/23/2021  12:38:06 PM'),
('63252595',    '21',   '5/23/2021  12:38:09 PM'),
('63252595',    '75',   '5/23/2021  12:38:10 PM'),
('63252595',    '77',   '5/23/2021  12:38:12 PM'),
('64252595',    '29',   '5/23/2021  12:38:15 PM'),
('64252595',    '26',   '5/23/2021  12:38:18 PM'),
('64252595',    '81',   '5/23/2021  12:38:20 PM'),
('64252595',    '40',   '5/23/2021  12:38:21 PM'),
('64252595',    '81',   '5/23/2021  12:38:24 PM'),
('64252595',    '83',   '5/23/2021  12:39:06 PM'),
('64252595',    '77',   '5/23/2021  12:39:07 PM'),
('65252595',    '41',   '5/23/2021  12:39:12 PM'),
('65252595',    '81',   '5/23/2021  12:39:16 PM'),
('65252595',    '37',   '5/23/2021  12:39:20 PM'),
('65252595',    '18',   '5/23/2021  12:39:56 PM'),
('65252595',    '18',   '5/23/2021  12:40:03 PM'),
('65252595',    '77',   '5/23/2021  12:40:15 PM'),
('65252595',    '36',   '5/23/2021  12:40:46 PM'),
('65252595',    '77',   '5/23/2021  12:40:53 PM')
```

**EXPECTED RESULTS:**
From this `#Data` table, the results I would expect to see would be:

| Header | EventId | EventDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 62252595 | 81 | 5/23/2021 12:34:03 PM |
| 65252595 | 81 | 5/23/2021 12:39:16 PM |

Header #'s 63252595 and 64252595 would not qualify because between the first instance of 81 and the first instance of 77 (partition by Header order by EventDate), there exists a 75 at `5/23/2021  12:38:10 PM` and an 83 at `5/23/2021  12:39:06 PM` respectively (both of which in exclusion list). I hope this clears up some confusion.

---

**EDIT:** After some thinking, I wonder if it would be possible to simplify this using a `CASE` expression. Using the example data from the `#Data` table above, I wrote this query:

```
select *
from (
    select * from (
        select *, id=case when EventId = 81 then 1 
                            when EventId = 77 then 2
                            when EventId in (60, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 83, 85, 86, 87, 103, 154, 166, 197, 199) then 5 else 0 end
        from #data) a
    where id <> 0)b
    order by 3
```

What this does is filters out all of the 'allowable' events and makes it so that I can filter to only see the unencumbered events where `id`=1 and then follows with a 2. What I'm not sure of as of yet is how to get it to show me only entries of `id`=1 with a following 2.

Comment: Your sub queries can return multiple values, so change them to return a single value minimum for the start and maximum for the end

Comment: Your sample data has all but two events happening at the same time.  Does that really happen in your data?  If so, particular if multiple 81s and/or 77s happen at the same timestamp, there is no way to determine which really happened first.

Comment: @MatBailie I used concatenation to get my single quotes and parentheses for that, and in the process I believe the seconds/milliseconds were truncated. I hadn't noticed that, thank you for pointing it out. If current recommendations do not pan out, I will adjust those time stamps.

Comment: Please add the desired results for the sample data.  For example, it's unclear if you want the row with eventid=6 or not; it happens after an End event, but before the very last End event.

Comment: I adjusted the timestamps @MatBailie. Sorry for the confusion, but EventID 6 will never be pulled, I will only need to pull EventID 81, but only where there's a subsequent EventID 77, in between these two does not exist an EventID in the exclusion list.

Comment: If the events go in this order what should be the result? 81,00,81,11,77 (Two starts, one end, no excepted events) - should the first or second 81 row be returned? Similarly, what about 81,00,77,199,77 or 81,199,81,00,77?

Comment: Great question @MatBailie. For both of the 2 starts examples you gave, I'm going to say the second 81. For the 2 end example, the first 77.

Comment: You phrased that as if you're not quite sure?  And do you really mean that there are some cases where you want the 77 to be returned? If so, please edit and clarify your question, it currently reads as if you only ever want the 81 with some logic to determine which 81 to return if any...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that a start event (81) always starts a new "frame" from that row onwards, and an end event (77) always starts a new frame from the following row onwards.

I'm also going to assume that you're only interested in frames where both a start and end event are present, and that the frame contains no excepted events *(I'll just use 00 as random allowable events and 199 as the only excepted event)*.

For example...

```
[81,00,81,00,77,00,81,199,77]
=> frame 0 = [81,00]
=> frame 1 = [81,00,77]
=> frame 2 = [00]
=> frame 3 = [81,199,77]
```

In that example only the 2nd frame's start event would be returned (the others missing start and/or end events, or containing the excepted event).

```
WITH
  frame_start AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    CASE
      WHEN
        81 = eventid
      OR
        77 = LAG(eventid) OVER (PARTITION BY header ORDER BY eventdate)
      THEN
        1
      ELSE
        0
    END
      AS new_frame
  FROM
    #data
),
  framed AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    SUM(new_frame) OVER (PARTITION BY header ORDER BY eventdate) AS frame_id
  FROM
    frame_start
)
SELECT
  header, MIN(eventdate)
FROM
  framed
GROUP BY
  header, frame_id
HAVING
  SUM(CASE WHEN eventid IN (81,77) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 2
  AND
  MAX(CASE WHEN eventid IN (199, etc) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Demo : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d54493c87629e3e59759ac9d119ec6ad

Explanation:

The first CTE adds a column called `new_frame`.

- `1` = current row is 81,or previous row is 77
- `0` = everything else

This marks the start of each new frame (as described at the top here).

The next CTE assigns an id to every row in each frame, by cumulatively summing the new_frame, in datetime order. The id starts at 0, then is incremented on each row by that row's new_frame value (if new_frame=0, keep the same id as the previous row, if new_frame=1 increment the id by 1).

At this point the header's rows are broken down in to frames (as described at the top here).

The final query groups by the frame and then filters the results with a HAVING clause.  The first check is that the number of rows in the frame with 81 or 77 must total 2. The second check is that no rows in the frame can have an excepted event. If all checks pass, return the minimum timestamp in the frame, which by definition comes from the first row in the frame.

Comment: Apologies for numerous edits, I'm doing this on a phone.

Comment: This seems to be nearly working as intended. I went back and added some logic to reduce my dataset to only include headers that have both an 81 and 77, and that made things work quicker but also alleviated some incorrect results. The only issue I see is that it's pulling the date for eventid 77 (at least in some cases), but I need it to pull the date only for eventid 81. I'd modify it myself, but honestly, I don't fully understand the logic here.

Comment: @jw11432 Edit the dbfiddle test data to demonstrate the problem and paste the link here.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=40e26dcaca18d348d45dcef3fb44c6aa

Comment: @jw11432 That's because your data once again has no seconds. So, multiple events are happening at the same time.

Comment: @jw11432 I added an identity column so I could add that id to the ORDER BY clauses in the window functions. That makes it deterministic, but the order the rows are inserted in is not guaranteed, so don't rely on that. Fix the data so that no two rows happen at the same time (for the same header). https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a512df355c61526e9384bf8db4bee62b

Answer (score 0):

It would be handy to see the actual expected results for the sample data so I don't actually know if this is correct, it looks like you just need to calculate date ranges per each header:

```
with h as (
  select *, 
    Min(case when eventid=81 then eventdate end) over(partition by header) Sdate, 
    Max(case when eventid=77 then eventdate end) over(partition by header) Edate
  from #data
)
select header, eventId, EventDate
from h
where eventdate between SDate and EDate
and EventId not in(60, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 83, 85, 86, 87, 103, 154, 166, 197, 199)
order by eventdate;
```

Comment: Should note that if there are multiple start and end events *(as in the OP's sample data)*, this will pull everything from the first-start to the last-end.  As mentioned, without expected results for the sample data, it's impossible to know if that's desired or not.

Comment: Granted this is making some assumptions from the supplied data, for which the dates for eventId 81/77 are identical. Also just noted that I thought at a glance there was one group of eventIds per header, it's hard to tell with such similar numbers - test data of single digits would have been easier to consume.

Comment: Also just to note that the OPs "singular" case makes the assumption of a single start/end event per header - so is the sample data correct?!

Comment: Thanks Stu. Yes, sample data is correct. My goal would be to pull the data of the first EventID 81 (regardless of how many there are for a given Header) up until the first EventID 77.

Comment: @jw11432 so in which case, your sample data also shows 77 always follows 81 by date, so would a `min`criteria for both start and end date work for you?

Comment: As I'm looking at real data right now in my DB, I think I actually need to go with a reverse of what was originally offered: a max(81) and a min(77). Reason being, I see one example where an 81 exists many times, but 77 exists only once. I'm going to err on the side of caution and presume on behalf of my requester that the range of these events should be as succinct as possible. I hope I've explained that clearly.